# Trouble implementing ActiveModel with class attributes on using DelayedJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, delayed-job, activemodel

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and DelayedJob 2.1 and I am trying to implement a "Contact Us" form myself using ActiveModel functionalities. So...

... in my model file I have:

```
class ContactUs
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations


  attr_accessor :full_name, :email, :subject, :message

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.keys.each do |attr|
      instance_variable_set "@" + attr.to_s, attributes[attr.to_sym]
    end
  end


  validates :full_name,
    :presence   => true

  validates :email,
    :presence   => true

  validates :subject,
    :presence   => true

  validates :message,
    :presence   => true


  def persist
    @persisted = true
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

... in my view file I have:

```
<%= form_for @contact_us, :url => contact_us_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :full_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :subject %>
  <%= f.text_area  :message %>
<% end %>
```

... in my router file I have:

```
match 'contact_us' => 'pages#contact_us', :via => [:get, :post]
```

... in my controller file I have:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def contact_us
    case request.request_method

    when 'GET'
      @contact_us = ContactUs.new

    when 'POST'
      @contact_us = ContactUs.new(params[:contact_us])

      # ::Pages::Mailer.delay.contact_us(@contact_us) # If I use this code, I will get an error with the 'full_name' attribute (read below for more information)
      ::Pages::Mailer.contact_us(@contact_us).deliver # If I use this code, it will work
    end
  end
end
```

*All works, except when I use the `::Pages::Mailer.delay.contact_us(@contact_us)` code with the method `full_name` related to the `full_name` class attribute in the email template* (however, it works when in the email template I do *not* call the `full_name` method).  That is, when I use the following email template with Dalayed Job I get an `undefined method 'full_name\' for #<ContactUs:0x000001041638c0> \n/RAILS_ROOT/app/views/pages/mailer/contact_us.html.erb`:

```
MESSAGE CONTENT:
<br /><br />

<%= @message_content.full_name %> # If I comment out this line it will work.
<br />
<%= @message_content.email %>
<br />
<%= @message_content.subject %>
<br />
<%= @message_content.message %>
```

When I use the above email template *without* Dalayed Job (that is, with the `::Pages::Mailer.contact_us(@contact_us).deliver` code) it works.

The related mailer code is:

```
class Pages::Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default_url_options[:host] = <my_web_site_URL>
  default :from => "<my_email_address@provaider_name.com"

  def contact_us(message_content)
    @message_content = message_content

    mail(
      :to      => <my_email_address@provaider_name.com>,
      :subject => "Contact us"
    ) do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

However, if I send a simple email (using the `::Pages::Mailer.delay.contact_us(@contact_us)`) containing a `@message_content.inspect` instead of `@message_content.full_name` I get the following output (note that the `full_name` instance variable exists!) when I receive the email:

```
#<ContactUs:0x000001013fc378 @full_name="Sample name text", @email="sample@email_provider.com", @subject="Sample subject text", @message="Sample message text", @validation_context=nil, @errors={}>
```

**What is the problem with Dalayed Job and how can I solve that?**

---

I really don't understand why this happens since I have `full_name` working as-like, for example, the `email` attribute for which all works. I also tried to restart my Apache2 server.

Comment: What if you rename a full_name to something else(fullname) without _? I'm not sure, but there could be a bug in delayed job when it serializes/deserializes @contact_us object.

Comment: You're restarting your delayed_job workers too right when changing the model with full_name?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, DelayedJob doesn't allow attribute accessors in models. I learned that the hard way, after many, many hours of trying to get it to work. If you create a custom DelayedJob job, you would be able to create attributes specifically for that job's class.